# How to define checkconstraint for 2 boolean columns of the table using sqlalchemy core only

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.5

I have a model:

```
    calendar = Table('calendar', metadata,
                      Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                      Column('event_name', String),
                      Column('start_time', DateTime(timezone=True)),
                      Column('end_time', DateTime(timezone=True)),
                      Column("created_by_id", Integer, ForeignKey("users.id")),
                      Column('bool_applicable_to_all', Boolean),
                      Column('bool_leave', Boolean),
                 UniqueConstraint('event_name','start_time', name="uniq_event_nm_start_time"),
                CheckConstraint('bool_applicable_to_all' != 'bool_leave',                 name='bool_all_applicable_bool_leave_not_together'
))
```

How to ensure that the 2 columns defined in the checkconstraint have opposite boolean values for the row at any point of time?
Using sqlalchemy 1.0, postgresql 9.5 +

Comment: if it were me, I'd just use the one boolean column and use the inverse of it in app wherever appropriate.

Comment: @SuperShoot, constraints defined at model level are to be done at priority to throw exceptions than in code

Comment: 2 bools, that must always be opposite == 1 bool.